# In Washington State, is a petition void or nul if there's no judge's signature for 476 days after filing with clerk's stamp?

Tags: civil-procedure, washington

Is there a "lazy judge rule" for civil procedure in WA state?

In Indiana:
Failure to Rule on a Motion and Delay of Judgments
Under T.R. 53.2, if a judge takes a cause tried to the court under advisement and fails to determine any issue of law or fact within *ninety (90) days* of the submission of all pending  matters, the case may be withdrawn from the judge.
Ind. T.R. 53.2(A).Trial Rule 53.1 and 53.2
https://www.in.gov/courts/iocs/files/pubs-trial-court-failure-to-rule-on-motion-and-delay-of-judgments.pdf

In California:
Every California judge is familiar with the requirement to issue timely decisions under a constitutional provision (Article VI, Section 19) that sets a deadline for judicial decisions: *90 days after the matter is submitted* for decision.
https://www.manatt.com/manatt/media/Media/PDF/05-Understanding-the-90-Day-Rule,-30-LA-Lawyer-11,-Dec-2007.pdf

WA Constitution SECTION 20 DECISIONS, WHEN TO BE MADE. Every cause submitted to a judge of a superior court for his decision shall be decided by him within ninety days from the submission thereof